# Optimisation tag

Tags: discussion

I apparently *overoptimised*:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5139387#5139387

Besides the breakdown, the discussion had some suggestions. So, what do you think about:

- [optimisation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation)
- its relation to [performance-tuning](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tuning)
- prevention of similar future mistakes

Comment: Anybody with the rep to view closed questions on the stats site might want to review the fallout from a similar incident a year ago at http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/837.

Answer (score 4):

The new use of [optimisation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation) appears to focus on questions asking for better ways to do things rather than "optimization" in the sense of finding the best value of an objective function subject to constraints.  (Applications of the latter in GIS include route finding and site selection.)  I get the idea but question the word used to describe it, due to this ambiguity.

I also wonder what the perceived value would be in applying a tag to all such questions (of which I guess there are a great many).  I'm not suggesting it's without value; I'm just asking what the intended value is.

Comment: It doesn't cover just mathematical optimisation, because I thought it too narrow to be useful. More general, algorithmic optimisation. The purpose was to collect topical questions both as a reference for learning and for the obvious improvement when searching. Most examples that I found were about speed, but there were also some interesting ones about size and bandwidth use. Do you really think a lot more would fall under this umbrella?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you've just given a great description of *performance tuning*! What distinction is intended with "optimisation"?

Comment: Storage and bandwidth saving hardly fall under that (economic performance tuning?). Or the fastest/easiest way to complete a task witha GUI program. Or even optimisation for elegance, brevity (think code or proof beauty). :)